# How do I write a function that matches anagrams and put them into a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

Hi stackoverflow community! Can someone please take a look at my code and advise? Is my sorting function wrong? I've tried comparing the values of individual characters within my for of loop, but it doesn't work. Also, can I know when can I put () after calling a function/variable, is it wrong to put parentheses after `newStr()` and `sortedWord()` ?

I am stuck on this question. To write a function that takes returns all the anagrams of a word in a list. Inputs are the word and a list of strings `anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']) => ['aabb', 'bbaa']`.

Here is my code:

```
function anagrams(word, words) {
  let sortedWord = word.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.localecompare(b);
  });
  let newArr = [];
  for (str of words){
    let newStr = str.sort(function(a,b){return a.localecompare(b)});
    if (newStr() == sortedWord()) {
      newArr.push(str);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Why the parentheses after `newStr()` and `sortedWord()`?

Comment: *"take a look at my code and advise?"* That is not a good question. It should be about a problem you encountered.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. Have edited the question. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: is it wrong to place parentheses after ```newStr``` and ```sortedword```? Cuz i dont need to call for its execution here?

Comment: `()` when used with a function triggers its execution. Wrapping something in `()` can influence the order of operations (e.g. `(1 + 2) * 3`). Adding `()` after something that is not a function will trigger an error because it treats the "left part" as a function - which you will see when you fix the `.sort` is not a function error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only arrays can be sorted using `sort()`. So `split()` before sorting and use `join()` to convert to string again

```js
function anagrams(word, words) {
  let sortedWord = word.split('').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  }).join('');
  let newArr = [];
  for (str of words) {
    let newStr = str.split('').sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.localeCompare(b)
    }).join('');
    if (newStr == sortedWord) {
      newArr.push(str);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']))
```